# 2D Pointer to 2D Pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d

I forgot most of my C, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question. Because I need to separate a string of words into individual words.

```
#include "argsInfo.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Parses string argument which contains words
 * separated by whitespace.  It returns an
 * argsInfo data structure which contains an
 * array of the parsed words and the number
 * of words in the array.
 */

argsInfo getArgsInfo(char * string) {
    argsInfo info;
    char ** temp;
    int nWords=1;
    int i=0;
    int j,k;
    //Test if the the input string is empty
    if (string[0] == '\0'){
        nWords=0;
    }else{
        //First I need to check how long the input String is, as-well as cout how many words are in the string.
        while (string[i] != '\0'){
            if (string[i] == ' '){
               nWords++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    //This allocates enough memory for each word.
    temp = (char**) malloc(nWords*sizeof(char*));

    for (j=0;j<nWords;j++){
        temp[j] = (char*) malloc(i*sizeof(char));
    }
    j=0;
    k=0;
    // If I encounter a white space, it signifies a new word, and I need to move it to the next element
    while (j < i){
        if (string[j] == ' '){
            k++;
        }
        temp[k][j] = string[j];
        j++;
    }
    info.argc = nWords;
    info.argv = temp;
    return info;
}
```

That 3rd last LINE. THAT'S where I think the problem is. `info.argv = temp;`

This is what the struct looks like:

```
 typedef struct {
    int argc;
    char ** argv;
 } argsInfo;
```

Example Input and Output:

Input: "ax bcd efghij"

Output: ax

If I remove the k++ line, the output becomes: ax bcd efghij

Likewise, if I input a b c. Only 'a' will show up when I run through the array.

Comment: Note: `while (string[i] != '\0'){` loop over counts words when consecutive spaces occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this part is inefficient but works:

```
for (j=0;j<nWords;j++){
    temp[j] = (char*) malloc(i*sizeof(char));
}
```

You are using the value of `i` which will be equal to the total number of characters in your original input string. This means that for each separate word you are allocation enough room to store the original sentence which is a waste of space.
You could, for example, while you are counting words, also remember the longest word seen thus far and use that as your allocation factor which will probably be much less than the whole sentence. We start the length at 1 to include the terminating character `'\0'`

```
int longest = 1;
int tempLength = 1;
//Test if the the input string is empty
if (string[0] == '\0'){
    nWords=0;
}else{
    //First I need to check how long the input String is, 
    //as-well as count how many words are in the string.
    while (string[i] != '\0'){
        if (string[i] == ' '){
           if(tempLength > longest) {
               longest = tempLength;
           }
           nWords++;
        } else {
            tempLength++; // count characters of current word
        }
        i++;
    }
}

for (j=0;j<nWords;j++){
    temp[j] = (char*) malloc(longest*sizeof(char));
}
```

Finally, the last part of your code needs a fix. It doesn't work because you are using `j` as an index in the overall sentence and as an index in a single word. You never reset `j`.
Let's say the first word is

```
apple
```

Once you encounter a space, you will have:

```
j = 5
temp[0] = "apple"
```

Now you increment `k` to 1 but `j` stays the same so you will start storing characters of the next word from position 5 instead of 0:

```
temp[1][5] = string[5];
```

Instead of:

```
temp[1][0] = string[5];
```

Therefore, you have 3 indexes to worry about:

- Index `a` that iterates over the input string.
- Index `b` that iterates over a single word of the string.
- Index `c` that iterates over the array of words.

The code:

```
int a, b, c;
for(a = 0, b = 0, c = 0; a < i; a++) {  // index i holds the total number of chars in input string
    if(string[a] != ' ') {
        temp[c][b] = string[a];
        b++;
    } else {
        temp[c][b] = '/0'; // add terminating character to current word
        b = 0;
        c++;
    }
}
info.argc = nWords;
info.argv = temp;
return info;
```

Comment: I was planning on fixing that i thing before, but didn't think of using the longest word until you mentioned it. Thanks your second part also works. I'm going to look over it a few times until I understand why yours works but mine doesn't. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3365695 you are very welcome :) Check out my edit for why your last part doesn't work.

Comment: @user3365695 I also suggest you to look at WhozCraig's solution which is more complex/advanced but also more efficient since it does everything in a single scan of the input.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this is what you were after. This should only require scanning the string *once*. Your index math has several issues:

- Your calculation of `i` is inefficient.
- The hoops `nWords` seems to go through questionable
- You don't seem to be interested in terminating each word, which is *very* bad.

That said, walk through the following *very* carefully in a debugger to see how it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

argsInfo getArgsInfo(const char * s)
{
    argsInfo info = {0,NULL};

    while (*s)
    {
        // find start of next word
        while (*s && isspace((unsigned char)*s))
            ++s;

        // find end of next word
        const char *beg = s;
        while (*s && !isspace((unsigned char)*s))
            ++s;

        if ((s - beg) > 0)
        {
            char **tmp = realloc(info.argv, (info.argc+1)*sizeof(*tmp));
            if (tmp)
            {
                info.argv = tmp;
                tmp[info.argc] = malloc((s - beg + 1) * sizeof(char));
                if (tmp[info.argc] != NULL)
                {
                    memcpy(tmp[info.argc], beg, s-beg);
                    tmp[info.argc++][s-beg] = 0; // <<= TERMINATE
                }
                else
                {
                    perror("Failed to allocate string");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                perror("Failed to expand string pointer array");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    return info;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you chose a static declaration of `argsInfo info` rather than a pointer and dynamic allocation?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It isn't static; its *automatic*, and the OP's code used by-value return originally so I was looking for a drop-in replacement. Honestly though, I wouldn't dynamically allocate `argsInfo` anyway. There is no need for that structure to be heap-allocated; only the pointer array and its content need be so.

Comment: Makes sense. My only thought was a later created `freeInfo (info))` function that would then only be able to free the char arrays and pointer to array of chars, instead of also being able to free the pointer to struct as well. Just a curiosity really. Great solution.

Comment: Yeah, were I going to code this for myself I would have passed in the `argsInfo` by address for population and returned error/success state as the function result (I loathe functions that don't provide a way to tell you they worked or not). Similarly, a `freeArgsInfo(argsInfo* ai)` would dovetail nicely with that. Twas a good observation on your part. Glad you found the answer useful.